# How to use C# namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to C# but I have worked a little bit for my classes. When I worked in C#for classes, our teacher used to tell us the namespaces that we needed for completing the assignment.

I wanted to know where do I find all the collection of the namespace for C#. 
One of my friends directed me to this site 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netframework-4.0

but some of the namespaces did not work for example,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlmA5.jpg)

I am working on a small project with ASP.NET MVC and wanted to try different namespaces

Comment: When you say "all", you need to keep in mind that there are some namespaces built into the .NET framework, then there's some that Microsoft delivers seperately in downloadable "loose DLL's" and then there's some that Microsoft delivers via the NuGet package management system, and then there's an infinite number put together by 3rd parties. The documentation is a good place to start if you want to find out what is provided by the framework. If you have specific questions about loading a particular assembly, you'll need to include the exact error information (not a pic) in your question.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure you don't make silly mistakes that you can prevent yourself, such as forgetting a period within a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused, or are possibly not asking the question correctly. The link you provided does contain a list of the different libraries (namespaces) available in the C# API.

If you try to use a namespace in your own code, and it does not resolve, you may need to add an assembly reference to bring that namespace into your project. VS usually does a pretty decent job of guessing what assembly, or missing using statement is required if you either press alt+enter, or click the context drop down under the missing library (denoted by the red squiggly).

Either way, you should just start coding your MVC project, and then google the issues you come up with directly. Asking for all the namespaces is very very vague.

Comment: Don't you mean the .Net API?

Comment: You are correct, I am asking the wrong question maybe. What I am trying to know is- how do C sharp developer know about the namespaces and which one to use. When I ask my friends the same question they tell me to do my own research, I do agree with them, but the problem is I don't know where to start my research. 

For example, if I am working on an ASP.Net MVC web app for a banking application, and I would like to pull data from the database and maybe encrypt the sensitive data when getting from the database. Where should I start looking for the correct namespace with appropriate classes?